# shouldStartProvisioning error for android simulator on mobilefirst

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Recently migrated an app from worklight 6.2 to 7.0. All works great on the mobile web application preview running locally. What does NOT work is the android preview on eclipse using mobilefirst. The splash screen doesn't fully load up. The only error I see at the moment is

```
ReferenceError: shouldStartProvisioning is not defined
    initCallback/<()
     worklight.js:9680
    WL.DeviceAuth.__isCertificateExists()
     worklight.js:18942
    initCallback()
     worklight.js:9667
    __WLClient/this.createProvisioningChallengeHandler/challengeHandler.handleChallenge/<()
     worklight.js:9643
    __WLDeviceAuth/this.init/<()
     worklight.js:6662
    WL.DeviceAuth.__initDeviceAuthManager()
     worklight.js:18953
    __WLDeviceAuth/this.init()
     worklight.js:6662
    __WLClient/this.createProvisioningChallengeHandler/challengeHandler.handleChallenge()
     worklight.js:9642
    AbstractChallengeHandler/this.startChallengeHandling()
     worklight.js:9358
    executeChallenge()
     worklight.js:9281
    __WLClient/this.checkResponseForChallenges()
     worklight.js:9183
    window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest<.onWlFailure()
     worklight.js:3606
    bind/<()
     worklight.js:957
    window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request<.respondToReadyState()
     worklight.js:1177
    window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request<.onStateChange()
     worklight.js:1112
```

This is from worklight.js

```
function initCallback(result) {
                if (challengeHandler.isCertificateChallengeResponse(challenge)) {
                    WL.DeviceAuth.saveCertificate(
                    //success callback
                    function() {
                        var deviceAuthSettings = {
                            token : challenge.ID.token,
                            isProvisioningEnabled : true,
                            provisioningEntity : challenge.ID.entity
                        };
                        challengeHandler.getDeviceAuthDataAsync(deviceAuthSettings);
                    },
                    //failure callback
                    function(err) {
                        WL.DiagnosticDialog.showDialog(WL.ClientMessages.wlclientInitFailure, WL.ClientMessages.saveCertificateFailure, false, true, {}, err);
                    }, challenge.ID.entity, challenge.certificate, challengeHandler.realm);
                    //handle save certificate
                } else {
                    //handler device auth
                    WL.DeviceAuth.__isCertificateExists(challenge.ID.entity,
                    // success callback
                    function(result) {
                        var isCertificateExists = WL.Utils.getCordovaPluginResponseObject(result, "isCertificateExists");
                        isCertificateExists = ("true" == isCertificateExists);
                        if (isCertificateExists) {
                            var deviceAuthSettings = {
                                token : challenge.ID.token,
                                isProvisioningEnabled : true,
                                provisioningEntity : challenge.ID.entity
                            };
                            challengeHandler.getDeviceAuthDataAsync(deviceAuthSettings);
                        } else {
                            shouldStartProvisioning();
                        };
                    },
                    // failure callback
                    function() {
                        WL.DiagnosticDialog.showDialog(WL.ClientMessages.wlclientInitFailure, WL.ClientMessages.deviceAuthenticationFail, false, true, challenge);
                    });

                    function shouldStartProvisioning() {
                        if (!challenge.ID.allowed) {
                            //submiting an empty answer so it will resend, and then get the 401 again, hopefully is allowed
                            challengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer();
                        } else {
                            if (challengeHandler.createCustomCsr != undefined) {
                                challengeHandler.createCustomCsr(challenge.ID);
                            } else {
                                WL.Logger.warn("Function createJsonCsr() is deprecated. Use createCustomCsr() instead.");
                                challengeHandler.createJsonCsr(challenge.ID.entity, challengeHandler.realm, {token:challenge.ID.token});
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        };
```

Comment: Added more information. Clearly shouldStartProvisioning is present in this file, also it not an editable one. @Iden_ader

Answer (score 0):

I have done some internal and external searches but have not found any prior reports of this type of issue.  I have some suggestions that may help diagnose the issue further.  First, does the issue occur with new projects, or just the migrated project?  Could you check the output for the common resources preview as well to see if the same error occurs?  Just want to make sure that the error is unique to the failing scenario.  Next, what is the full build level of MobileFirst that you are using?  In eclipse, select Help -> About -> [MobileFirst icon].

Comment: Since this content is not an Answer, you should place it in a Comment to the Question. StackOverflow works a bit differently than newsgroups or forums - subsequent readers should be able to clearly identify Q & A. Everything else belongs in a Comment. You'll find more information in the Help center :-)

Comment: Issue only occurs with this project, a new one starts up just fine.

This issue is for the Android and iOs as the mobile web app starts up as expected.

MobileFirst version 7.0.0.00

Comment: Zachary, thanks for the feedback.  Regarding the version of MobileFirst, it should also contain a build level in the form of yyyymmdd, such as 7.0.0.00-20150710-1555.  If the version you are using is not recent, I would suggest applying the latest ifix from the IBM Fix Central site (https://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).  If after that the issue is still occurring, then the next step would be to raise a PMR with product support.  Thanks.